# How to capture Codenameone Errors in Deployment, blackscreen

Tags: codenameone, stack-trace

After Releasing a new version, I discovered the app is not working and gives a black screen, in deployment, so I had to server-compile extensivly to try and change code and discover where the error comes from, and deploy many times. I only have this screen without stacktrace. I am still trying to search for the problem. So what to do when the simulation does not show the error, but in deployment it does? Noitce I had to put a big try-catch block to catch this and send to a Dialog.

thank you

[image]

Comment: Did you connect the device with a cable and logcat? You should see the exception there in the logs and it would give you a stack trace with lines into the offending line in your code.

Comment: After spending hours and multiple complies deployment and showing dialogs.. finally caught the problem.. can you please guide me about logcat? Thank you

Comment: You can just google Android logcat device. It's mostly OS dependent

Comment: I installed Logsys apps for androids and gives alot of verbose, did not find any exceptions from my program, I also started to use Log.e, and Log.p(message, ERROR), still could not find error logs.

Comment: It's not necessarily just under your app but generally if you get an exception and don't swallow it (catch without Log.e() etc.) then you won't see anything

Comment: is there a best practices codenameone Log way to do things, the Log class does not support tagging, how would you recomend filtering out these android logs to focus on my exceptions or prints? thank you

Comment: The native logs and Codename One logs are two different things. With logcat you see the native logs, which include many additional logs to Codename One's logs. As for Codename One, you can assign each call to Log.p("xxx") the logging level, e.g. Log.p("xxx", Log.DEBUG), then in the init() you can specify the logging level you want, via Log.setLevel(...). See: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Log.html Also note that each Codename One log starts with the name of the calling thread, e.g. "EDT" or another thread you use: this can be useful to make a quick search.